# docker inspect with not-contains in the Go template

Tags: docker, go-templates

I saw some examples of

```
docker inspect -f {{ if ne "/some-name" .Name}}{{.Name}} {{end}} $(docker ps -q)
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for `template - Go Lang..` I read the following

> eq Returns the boolean truth of arg1 == arg2
>
> ne Returns the boolean truth of arg1 != arg2
>
> lt Returns the boolean truth of arg1 < arg2
>
> le Returns the boolean truth of arg1 <= arg2
>
> gt Returns the boolean truth > of arg1 > arg2
>
> ge Returns the boolean truth of arg1 >= arg2

Does anyone know of a way to use a `not contains` with the docker inspect command?

Answer (score 0):

No.  At the moment the Go language lacks supports for regular expressions, which would be the most potent way to support this functionality.

The complete list of supported functions:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/formatting/

Answer (score 0):

Only way I've found is `split` plus `len`.
Like this:

```
docker ps -q \
| xargs -rn1 docker inspect -f \
'{{.Name}}{{"\t"}}
{{- if (gt (split .Config.User "_"|len) 1) -}}
user {{printf "%#v" .Config.User}} has underscore
{{- else  -}}
user {{printf "%#v" .Config.User}} has no underscore
{{- end}}'
```